# Php echo not working on empty form field test

Tags: php, html

I'm finding that echo isn't working in my scripts. 
The stripped down script below is what I've been using to debug this, but the result has been the same.

Perhaps you can see something simple I've overlooked. Any help appreciated.

Additional details:

- Location: http://www.example.com/include/sandbox.php
- The web-server can execute php-scripts: `phpinfo();` presents PHP Version 5.3.24.
- No header lines to worry about.

(I'm wanting to check that a field is not empty before submitting to a database, and provide prompts or an echo on submit.)

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post'){
    if(!isset($fieldA)){
        echo "Error: Submission field empty.";
    }
    else{
        echo "Success! Submitted field wasn't empty.";
    }
}
?>

<h1> Example Title </h1>
<form method="post" action="sandbox.php" >
    <input type="text" name="fieldA" value="" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think you have to use the string 'post' as uppercase: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
..........
}
```

Try this one. or change the if condition like,

```
 if(!isset($_POST['fieldA'])){
     if(empty($_POST['fieldA'])) {
         echo "Error: Submission field empty.";
     }
        }
        else{
            echo "Success! Submitted field wasn't empty.";
        }
```